# Translation of a few Latin words (two 1600s church records)

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, paleography

These church records are mostly in Danish but contain a few Latin words, some of which I haven't been able to translate. I have marked the Latin in bold. I have also included links to the full church records to help with the handwriting.

The first one is a 1681 record of a woman being publicly absolved in church for having a child out of wedlock. It says (translated to English): "Kirsten, Jens Feydsøns daughter, made pregnant by Anders Matthsøn at Veye [a nearby farm]", and then the Latin "sutor [vestianis]". Sutor is cobbler, but what is "vestiaris" (if that is indeed what it says)?

[image: absol1681]

> 2 Kirsten Jens Feydsøns datter besoffued aff Anders
> Matthsøn paa Veye **Sutor vestiaris**

Full page: https://www.sa.dk/ao-soegesider/da/billedviser?epid=22743682#476901,85381944 (left page, bottom)

---

The second record is a 1651 burial of a man. It says (translated to English): "I buried Jens Fajdtzøn, [he was] 38 years old," and then the Latin "hydrope [Tovreptj?] exsperavit. Sutor". So it appears he died from hydropsy and was also a cobbler, but what does the second word mean?

[image: burial1651]

> 27 Septemb: begroff ieg Jens Fajdtzøn
> 38 Aar gammell, **hydrope [Tovreptj?]
>
> exsperavit. Sutor**

Full page: https://www.sa.dk/ao-soegesider/da/billedviser?epid=22743682#476901,85381670 (right page, lower half)

Comment: Perhaps the first is a form of *vestiarius*, "of or belonging to clothes", "clothesdealer"? In which case *sutor* may mean more generally "a patcher up" (repairer). So, then -- he was a tailor who fixed worn clothing?

Comment: Could you translate the Danish as well? That might help.  I have no idea what language "veye" is or what it means.  "Besoffued" and "Aar gammel" also puzzling.  Do they mean "made pregnant" and "old in years"?  I think "hydrope correptus exspiravit.  Sutor" could mean "he died having been stricken by dropsy.  A cobbler."

Comment: @MPW "patcher of clothes" is interesting, there are many tailors in the family.

Comment: @Vegawatcher I have included full English translations. I also thought something like "corruptus", but other genealogists disagree, and it does seem there's a top-line to make it a T under the Fa of "Fajdtzøns" above. Compare "Tørring" top left same link, fourth line second to last word

Comment: Just to be clear, "correptus" ("snatched away)  is different from "corruptus" ( "corrupted").  In either case, I cannot make a final "i/j" work grammatically.  Perhaps it is a Latinized masculine placename ending in a locative "i/j" like Tovrepti or Torrepti?  In that case, it would mean he died of dropsy in the town/city of XXXX.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't fit with any known Danish place names, and -pt- is an extremely unusual combination that is nearly only seen in loan words. I have however now identified Veye as a farm nearby.

Comment: My best guess is "hydrope conreptus/correptus" or "hydrope conrepto/correpto" ((one) seized/attacked by dropsy, despite the possibility of an initial "t."

Comment: I agree that makes more sense, but I'm not happy about that line... there's no Latin word it could be with a T?  :-/

Comment: I agree with @MPW that the first is a form of *vestiarius*, specifically, the phrase is "aff Anders [...] *sutore vestiario*", in the ablative. "aff" would be "a/ab" in Latin, which governs the ablative. Possibly, as suggested, a "repairer" of clothes, as opposed to shoes, leather or other objects.

Comment: @marquinho note: "aff" is a Danish word meaning "of" (as in he comes from this place), current spelling "af". Repairer/patcher of clothes is as mentioned a very reasonable translation. I will update the transcription.

Comment: An idea: Could it be "hydrops conreptus", if the line below the above F is a curlicue of a final -s in hydrops?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) This is how I parse and understand it: "besoffued(?) / aff A.M. / paa Veye sutore vestiario". I take your word that "besoffued"(?) stands for "impregnated". "aff" provides the agens: "by A.M.", as you suggested (and therefore corresponds to a Latin "ab"-phrase). I understand this is one possible meaning of "af" in Danish? The rest provides the identifying data for A.M. that were customary in old registers, i.e. his profession and residence: "mender/tailor at Veye"; this is in the ablative, as required of an agens phrase in Latin. Hope this is of some use :)

Comment: Right, sorry. The "af" is best translated as "by", he is the actor responsible for impregnating her. The "paa" (literally "on", curr. sp. "på") is the location indicator. "Besoffued" would presently be spelled "besoved" (-ffu- was used for -v- before the latter became common in Danish)

Comment: A thought, could the final letter on _corrept*_ be some kind of abbreviation sign for _-us_? I tried looking up some Tironian abbreviations but couldn't find a good list.